# Create vertical navigation in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I create a vertical navigation bar, which takes as much space as needed for  each button.

Example with 3 Buttons inside the navigation:
[image]

Example with 4 Buttons inside the navigation:
[image]

Notice how the height of the Button changes and only takes as much space as needed.

My try:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
      <Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow">Yellow 1</Label>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

How could i achieve this WPF XAML?

Comment: Kindly share the code.

Comment: I hope it doesn't come over like this, I tried it with dockPanel and other stuff but didn't manage it. Thats why I am asking

Comment: I understand, kindly share the code so that I can suggest the changes.

Comment: An "easy" way of doing this is to create an `ItemsControl`, using a `Grid` as the `ItemsPanel`.  Grids offer the sizing behavior you want, and the itemscontrol can provide an easy way of adding and removing buttons. (see https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html)

Comment: @Sham I added a code sample of my try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hard-code your buttons inside the xaml, you can use a simple UniformGrid with Colums="1"

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <UniformGrid Grid.Column="1" Columns="1">
         <Button Content="1" />
         <Button Content="2" />
         <Button Content="3" />
     </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Otherwise, if you want handle the buttons from the ViewModel you can use an ItemsControl:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding YourButtonVm}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the above answer, by Babbillumpa we cant hardcode Rows = 1 for UniformGrid. For the type of requirement, we need to mention Row attribute to 3 or 4 if you want 3 or 4 buttons inside UniformGrid.

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <UniformGrid Grid.Column="1" Rows="3">
         <Button Content="1" />
         <Button Content="2" />
         <Button Content="3" />
     </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right, i inverted "Rows" with "Columns"

Comment: @Babbillumpa if you just found it correct you can upvote as well thanks beforehand.